# improve performance of python django models.py query

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

I am loading the website data into Postgres using Python-Django, there are around 9 csv files that i am loading to database but its taking so long ~10 hrs to fetch the data from website, and load it to Postgres. I wanted to increase the performance of the query. Can you guys please help with that?

This is just 1 dataframe, but i have 9 more similar to that, overall data is less than 500k records

```
from django.db import models  
from django_pandas.managers import DataFrameManager  
import pandas as pd      
from sqlalchemy import create_engine  
import zipfile  
import os  
from urllib.request import urlopen     
import urllib.request  
import io  
from io import BytesIO  

class mf(models.Model):
    pg_engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@server:host/db')
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(urllib.request.urlopen('http://md_file.zip').read()))
    df1 = pd.read_csv(zf.open('nm.dat'),header=None,delimiter='|', index_col=0, names=['aaa', 'xxxx', 'yyy','zzz'])
    df1.to_sql('nm',pg_engine,if_exists='replace')
```

Comment: why dont you save files you are fetching on local drive?

Comment: We wanted to automate that process and the company doesnt like anything to save on local